# HY000 General error on prepared statement using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why do I keep getting the HY000 error (General error) with this query?

```
SET  @uid:=?;
SET  @uscore:=(SELECT `total_score` FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = @uid LIMIT 1);

SELECT `user_id`, `username`, `total_score` FROM `user`
WHERE `total_score` > @uscore
OR `user_id` = @uid
OR `total_score` < @uscore
ORDER BY `total_score` DESC
LIMIT 11
```

But if I remove the `SET` statements it works correctly:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `username`, `total_score` FROM `user`
WHERE `total_score` > 5000
OR `user_id` = 11
OR `total_score` < 5000
ORDER BY `total_score` DESC
LIMIT 11
```

However, the same query works perfectly fine when run on MySQL Workbench, just by replacing `?` with the `11`. Is there something I'm missing while connecting to the DBMS or something?

Comment: are you doing those `set` calls in the SAME `->prepare($sql)` call? You can't issue multiple statements in a single query call.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? The only thing I can think about is repeating the `(SELECT `total_score` FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = @uid LIMIT 1)` sub-query on every evaluation, but I don't think that's so efficient.

Comment: run them separately. `->query("SET ..."); ->query("SET ..."); ->query("SELECT ...");` The variables are per-connection, so will persist between your individual query calls.

Comment: But then how do I do the prepared statement to bind a value in the first `SET`?

Comment: Thank you! I works like a charm! Can you write that down as an answer so I can close this question?